# possible to release viewcontroller.view without releasing viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller which can't be released since it is a subclass with extra functionality... Anyway there are many of them, and I need the views to be released when they go offscreen.

removeFromSuperView vanishes the views but they remain in memory.  The only way I can get rid of the view from memory is to completely dealloc it.  However, when I access viewcontroller.view, it is just going to create the view again, isn't it?

The views themselves don't take up any significant memory until they are drawn for the first time, so...

Ideally I will have an array of views I can [ copy] into viewcontroller.view when they are needed (onscreen) and release completely to dealloc when they go offscreen, so that Cocoa knows to get rid of whatever internal graphics memory it is allocating.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you release the view controller if its a "subclass with extra functionality"?

Comment: Indeed, confused as to why subclasses are forced to be permanently resident...

Comment: I have a 'block' class which subclasses UIViewController and holds content and layout information, which I only want to set up once, when a page is loaded. I want dynamic control of the UIView, since this is what is eating up memory when I have a lot of these "blocks"

Comment: I even tried changing the relationship between Block and UIViewController so that instead of subclassing, block owns a viewcontroller as a member variable.  This means I have full control over when the viewcontroller gets deleted. Even when I completely release (gets dealloc'd) the viewcontroller after it has been drawn once, I don't gain any memory back.  I need to be able to free up this memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To release the view from your controller, use:

```
self.view = nil;
```

Later on, referencing `self.view` in a 'get' context will recreate the view (will reload from NIB or call `loadView`).

Also, never send a `dealloc` message explicitly to your view or any object.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the view in

```
- viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

and re-create it in

```
- viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

methods of your view controller